# Creating a variable with threee characteristics

Tags: r

I would like to create a variable "WKA" with three charakteristics: 0,1 and 2.

```
WKA should be 0 if WKA_ohneJB[, "QUANTITY"]>=1 && WKA_ohneJB[, "WKA"]==0,
WKA should be 1 if WKA_ohneJB[, "QUANTITY"]>=1 && WKA_ohneJB[, "WKA"]>=1,
WKA should be 2 if WKA_ohneJB[, "QUANTITY"]==0 && WKA_ohneJB[, "WKA"]==0
```

How can I implement this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `if/else` along with `&&`, we can use `ifelse` with `&` as `ifelse` is vectorized

```
WKA_ohneJB$newWKA <- with(WKA_ohneJB, ifelse(QUANTITY >=1 & WKA == 0, 0,
                  ifelse(QUANTITY >=1 & WKA >=1, 1, 2)))
```

---

Or with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
WKA_ohneJB <- WKA_ohneJB %>%
                mutate(newWKA = case_when(QUANTITY >= 1 & WKA== 0 ~ 0L,
                  QUANTITY >=1 & WKA >=1 ~ 1L,
                  QUANTITY == 0 & WKA == 0 ~ 2L, 
                    TRUE ~ NA_integer_))
```